# Who is throwing the InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

In the following code, who is throwing the `InterruptedException` caught at line-(K+1)?

```
public class Den implements Runnable {

    Object T = new Object(); 

    public void m1() {

        System.out.println("here ..  "); 
        synchronized(T){
            try {
                T.wait();  // line-K
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {  // line-(K+1)
                System.out.println("An InterruptedException is thrown ");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
                System.out.println("here  2"); 
        }    
    } // m1()

    @Override
    public void run() {m1();}

    public static void main (String ...jsdf) {    
        Den H = new Den();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(H);
        t1.start(); 
        t1.interrupt();        // line-W
    }
}
```

The output of this code is

```
run:
here ..  
An InterruptedException is thrown 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
here  2
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at prj.Dene.m1(Dene.java:12)
    at prj.Dene.run(Dene.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The stack trace tells that it's the `T.wait()` method that is throwing it-- as it should be, there's nothing else in the code that throws an `InterruptedException`.

But then-- `interrupt()` is called on the thread `t1` and `t1` is executing the `Runnable H` as its `Thread.target` object. 
How come `T` is receiving that interrupt? Is the `interrupt()` on `Thread.target` invoking in turn the `interrupt()`-s of objects it is waiting on? `Thread.interrupt()` is invoking a native `Thread.interrupt0()` -- can't see these.

TIA.

Comment: What mechanism you used to determine which thread encountered exception?

Comment: The `wait()` method is throwing the exception, obviously. Do you mean 'who is interrupting the thread'?

Comment: Causing the interruption (via `interrupt()` from a different thread) and throwing the InterruptedException are two entirely different things.  When your thread t1 goes into `wait` it *listens* for an interrupt, and when it "hears" one it throws the InterruptedException.

Answer (score 0):

`t1.interrupt();` is obviously the initiation of the interrupt.  You may be unaware, but this only "schedules" an interrupt; the target thread (t1) is not necessarily immediately disturbed... InterruptedException only occurs at well defined points so that you can handled this in code.

`wait()` is one of these well defined points (along w/ `sleep()`, and some I/O operations).

In your case, the system injects an exception inside the `wait()` call.  Don't put toooooo much into the line number reported.